# SQL Subquery with where in and group by

Tags: sql, subquery

This is the question I'm trying to answer:

*From the businesses table, find all owners that own more than five restaurants. Then find the 10 most popular locations for restaurants (using postal_code) amongst the owners who have 5 restaurant or more. The final result should return the 10 most popular areas (postal_code) and the frequency with which they appear in our group of owners who own five restaurants or more. The result should have two columns (postal_code and frequency) and should be presented in descending order of frequency.*

I have created the query below but it's not working as expected. What am I missing?

```
SELECT postal_code, COUNT(postal_code) AS 'frequency'
FROM businesses
WHERE owner_name IN (SELECT owner_name
                     FROM businesses
                     GROUP BY owner_name
                     HAVING COUNT(business_ID) > 5
                     ORDER BY COUNT(business_ID) DESC)
GROUP BY postal_code
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific in several ways.)

Comment: are all businesses "restaurant "? or do you need a where clause to limit to just restaurants?  Also... "It's not working as expected" doesn't tell us what's wrong. or what requirement isn't being met.  Keep in mind; we can't see anything we don't know anything unless you tell us.  the SQL helps; but sample data; results your getting and expected results given your sample data gets us further along the path to understanding the problem

Comment: [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Note you state *have 5 restaurant or more*, so that should be `>=5`

Comment: Ordering the subquery results could be an error depending on the platform. It isn't relevant either way.

Comment: If you add your tables it's easier